# How to remove element from array if string does not match condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ecmascript-6

if settlementDesc string has without ":" colon remove that entry from the array its not happening with below code , what is implemented wrong in below code it is returning both elements ?

main.js

```js
const messages =  [{
     "settlementCode": "85",
     "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85)||Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
    },
    {
     "settlementCode": "99",
     "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
    }
]
        
function validateEntries (messages) {
  if(!messages){ return [] };
  let filteredMsg = messages.filter(item => !item.settlementDesc.includes(":")) 
  return filteredMsg;
};
    
console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

expected output

because settlementDesc contains colon it should not be omitted and we should get in filtered response.

```
[
{
    "settlementCode": "99",
    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
}
]
```

Comment: You area already doing the work. `let messages = [...]; messages = validateEntries(messages);`

Comment: Reassigning messages variable after filtering is what you want to do.

Comment: You are not passing the right variable into validateEntries? Should be ```validateEntries(messages)```

Comment: in your code you're passing `rejectMessage` to `validateEntries()` -- where is rejectMessage defined?

Comment: You must remove `!` from `!item.settlementDesc.includes(":")` to get the object with `:`

Comment: There's @Fraction 's comment too -- in the first part of the question you're asking to remove the element(s) where the colon is present, but your desired output is to retrieve the element(s) with a colon?

Answer (score 0):

Using filter

```js
const messages = [{
    "settlementCode": "85",
    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85)||Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
  },
  {
    "settlementCode": "99",
    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
  }
]
console.log(messages.filter(e => e.settlementDesc.includes(':')))
```

Correcting your code
Change the variable name to messages which contains the object

```js
const messages = [{
    "settlementCode": "85",
    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85)||Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
  },
  {
    "settlementCode": "99",
    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias.  (Código de error 85)"
  }
]

function validateEntries(messages) {
  if (!messages) {
    return []
  };
  let filteredMsg = messages.filter(item => item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))

  return filteredMsg;
};

console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

Comment: i should get the object that contains colon in the string not the pipe right

Comment: This isn't right. He needs to remove the ! to get the right results.

Comment: not sure where is the catch sometime it works sometime it does not

Comment: can you provide examples where it is working and where it is not in your question

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost there. Just pass `messages` instead of `rejectMessage` to your function:

```js
const messages= [{ "settlementCode": "85", "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85)||Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias. (Código de error 85)" }, { "settlementCode": "99", "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias. (Código de error 85)" } ]

 function validateEntries (messages) {
   if(!messages){ return [] };
     let filteredMsg = messages.filter(item => item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))
     return filteredMsg;
   };

console.log(validateEntries(messages))
```

You could also refactor some of the code to make it more concise:

```js
const messages= [{ "settlementCode": "85", "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85)||Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias. (Código de error 85)" }, { "settlementCode": "99", "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily unavailable to process your request.(Error Code 85):Lo sentimos,Intente de nuevo más tarde. Gracias. (Código de error 85)" } ]

let validateEntries = msgs => !msgs 
  ? [] 
  : msgs.filter(item => item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))

console.log(validateEntries(messages))
```

Comment: i should get the object that contains colon right we should omit object that does not contain colon : in your output it should be string with colon

Comment: This still isn't right. He needs to remove the ! to get the right results.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the ! from the filter function. And make sure you are passing the right variable into the function. It worked for me.

```js
function validateEntries (messages) {
  if(!messages){ return [] };
  let filteredMsg = messages.filter(item => item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))
    return filteredMsg
};

validateEntries(messages);
```